# Account Linking - OAUTH2 auth code exchange using Basic HTTP Auth?

Tags: actions-on-google

Our OAuth 2.0 server expects the client credentials for the auth-code-to-token exchange to be in a Basic HTTP Auth header, a common strategy detailed in the OAuth 2.0 RFC. Is there a flag that can be set on our account to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear we are exposing this setting via the Actions Console, but we do support this for properly configured clients.

I have reached out to the team responsible for Actions Console and will update this answer with instructions once we support this option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think my question was misunderstood or not clear. I'm certainly not making any request to support username and password. I was referring to [Section 2.3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1). It is a 'MAY' but was checking if Google client supported it (as several other major clients do) before we run off and modify our OAuth server.

Comment: Apologies. That is actually supported by our infrastructure, but it may not be exposed by the Actions Console. I will look into this and be back with you shortly, once we have an answer, I'll edit the above.

Answer (score 0):

We are also facing similar issue. Our OAuth 2.0 server expects client credentials should be coming in Basic HTTP Auth header, but looks like from the Actions console it is coming as a part of request body. As you have mentioned that provision is there in your infrastructure, so if you can have that provision in Actions console as well to send client credentials in Basic Auth header it would be great !